# main method not found using One-Jar

Tags: java, onejar

I am using [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) to combine my application and its dependencies into one jar file. I used the command line approach step by step. However, when running the jar file with java -jar one-jar.jar I recieve the following

```
error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.webtest.hc.Main
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.findClass(JarClassLoader.java:713)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.JarClassLoader.loadClass(JarClassLoader.java:630)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:336)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:168)
```

Here is my boot-manifest.mf :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0

Main-Class: com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot

One-Jar-Main-Class: com.webtest.hc.Main
```

and i followed the exact same instruction as it is in the One-Jar website

Comment: Are your files in root/main and root/lib? (Root is the projectfolder)

Comment: @thomas yes. my dependencies are in root/lib and my application.jar is in main which has this package : com/webtest/hc

Answer (score 0):

Your JAR is packaged incorrectly. The message error says Java can't find the One-Jar loader, which is `com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot` so you somehow ended up with a malformed archive even if you tried to follow the instructions on the One-Jar site.

***How do I know that the JAR is malformed?***

Well, from the JVM message we can guess you miss the following files if you try and open the JAR with a ZIP viewer:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/simontuffs/onejar/Boot.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Handler$1.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/Handler.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/JarClassLoader$ByteCode.class
com/simontuffs/onejar/JarClassLoader.class
boot-manifest.mf
```

***How do I fix the packaging process?***

It depends and we don't have the sources so can't tell. As a personal recommendation, I use Gradle as a build tool and it's well integrated with IDEs (Eclipse and Intellij) and [Capsule](https://github.com/puniverse/capsule), an alternative to One-Jar.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I unziped the JAR and I have all the class files that you mentioned

Comment: It can't be. Upload your JAR somewhere (Google Drive, Dropbox, whatever) and share the link, so I can tell you what's wrong with it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zyRO9WWrWmpydEBXEVoIjkroDU8XZgJE

Comment: Upload the JAR. Debugging screenshots is an art I still don't have the privilege to manage

Comment: Thank you Raffaele for looking at my screenshots. It's for my job I'm not sure if I am allowed to.

Comment: If you are allowed I can try to help. If you are not, I can only tell you that from the screen it *should* work, but somehow it *doesn't*. That *somehow* will remain a mystery to me (I hope less-than-so for you)

Comment: From the screen I see there are at least two different versions of your JAR (webmain-2.6.0.jar in the root and webmain-0.7.2.jar in `main/`) and there are program classes in `main/com/webmain/hc/`. It doesn't work this way

Comment: webmain-2.6.0 in what is the final jar product I unzipped it that's why its in the folder. But I got the One-Jar work ! but when I add it as an external jar to my eclipse project, it does not show the content of the inside jars ? Is it how it is supposed to be ?